# can I write "are occurred"?

Tags: verbs, relative-clauses, conjugation

I want to write a sentence about international crime. Which one is the correct way to write the sentence:

> - International crimes, which are occurred around the world...
> - International crimes, which occur around the world...

Comment: No, you can't write "*are occurred*". You could write "*are occurring*" or "*have occurred*", or just plain "*occur*" as you've done in your second sentence.

Comment: Even the grammatically correct one sounds odd.

Comment: _Are occurred_ is a Passive construction. Passive can only apply to transitive clauses. _Occur_ is an intransitive verb. Therefore, ...

Answer (score 1):

"Are" is present tense.  (Happening now)
"Occurred" is past tense.  (Happened previously)

That being said, "are occurred," is incorrect.

"Which occur" is correct.

As mentioned in the comments above, "are occurring" or "have occurred" would both be correct as well.

Answer (score 1):

"are occurred" mixes present tense and past participle, so does not work.
"which occur" is a simple present construction and is correct.

Depending on what you are writing for, 'occur' may be slightly formal - good for a report, not so good for light fiction, for instance. Consider, then, "which happen", "which are committed" or "which take place" as alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

For the 1st sentence :

If you wish to use it in the passive form, then I think instead of 'are occurred' you may consider 'are caused' , 'are brought about' or 'are triggered', etc.

For the 2nd sentence :

I think the passive voice is preferable. The crimes do not 'occur' by themselves, they are 'committed' by some people.

Consider:

Air crashes which occur due to inclement weather...

Murders/crimes/molestations which are committed inside the prison...